# How to enable specific dates taken from a database, in a jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to enable these dates on a datepicker. I am very new to this. How can I enable dates taken from a database to this function?

This is my code:

```
<script>

jQuery(function(){

    //var enableDays = ["2020-08-02","2020-08-03","2020-08-04"];

    var enableDays=["' . implode('", "', $dates) . '"];


    function enableAllTheseDays(date) {
        var sdate = $.datepicker.formatDate( 'yy-mm-dd', date)
        if($.inArray(sdate, enableDays) != -1) {
            return [true];
        }
        return [false];
    }

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays});
})

</script>
```

It works properly when I am giving my dates, `var enableDays = ["2020-08-02","2020-08-03","2020-08-04"]` in this format manually (as I have commented above).

But what I want to do is take available dates from database and enable those dates on my date picker.

I get available dates from database in this format.

`$dates=Array ( [0] => 2020-08-02 [1] => 2020-08-03 [2] => 2020-08-04 )`

After I use (`var enableDays=["' . implode('", "', $dates) . '"]`) this to convert above indexed array format to this square bracket format it unavailable all the dates.

Comment: Is the array in server side PHP? Then do a PHP array join. See: https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_string_join.asp Many languages have a join method for converting arrays to strings.

Answer (score 1):

This question lacks the "between" code. So it comes out from your MySQL using php correct? You want it the php array to go to JavaScript variable?

```
<?php
    
    // This is the input array... You did not explain, where it comes.. but here it is now:
    $dates = array(
        0 => '2020-08-02',
        1 => '2020-08-03',
        2 => '2020-08-04',
    );
    
    // Prints out as JavaScript dates variable, and implodes the php array with commas and "" around them
    echo '<script>var dates=' . json_encode($dates) . '</script>';
?>
```

**Output:**

```
<script>var dates=["2020-08-02", "2020-08-03", "2020-08-04"] </script>
```

Comment: @halfer Thank you for the addon. Absolutely brilliant and indeed much neater approach. I edited it into the answer, so future generation can carry on the legacy :) Cheers